# Grep with as least one matching value and at least one not matching

Tags: grep

I have some files, and I want grep to return the lines, where I have at least one string  Position:"Engineer" AND at least one string which does have Position not equal to "Engineer"
So in the below file should return only first line:

```
Position:"Engineer" Name:"Jes" Position:"Accountant" Name:"Criss" 
Position:"Engineer" Name:"Eva" Position:"Engineer" Name:"Adam"
```

I could write something like

```
grep 'Position:"Engineer"' filename | grep 'Position:"Accountant"'
```

And this works fine (I get only first line), but the thing is I don't know what are all of the possible values in Position, so the grep needs to be generic something like

```
grep 'Position:"Engineer"' filename | grep -v 'Position:"Engineer"'
```

But this doesn't return anything (as both grep contradict each other)

Do you have any idea how this can be done?

Comment: `grep -e '.*Engineer.*Accountant.*' -e '.*Accountant.*Engineer.*' file.txt`

Answer (score 1):

This line works :

```
grep "^Position:\"Engineer\"" filename | grep -v " Position:\"Engineer\""
```

The first expresion with *"$"* catch only the Position at the begining of line, the second expression with *" "* space remove the second "Postion" expression.

Comment: Thanks, I've fix this typo !

Comment: But this won't work when the positions are swapped, that is, when the non-engineer position comes first and the engineer position comes later.

Comment: Yes agreed, but there any other information about this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the pipe and additional subshell by using `awk` if that is allowed, e.g.

```
awk '
    $1~/Engineer/ {if ($3~/Engineer/) next; print}
    $3~/Engineer/ {if ($1~/Engineer/) next; print}
' file
```

Above just checks if the first field contains `Engineer` and if so checks if field 3 also contains `Engineer`, and if so skips the record, if not prints it. The second rule, just swaps the order of the tests. The result of the tests is that `Engineer` can only appear in one of the fields (either first or third, but not both)

**Example Use/Output**

With your sample input in `file`, you would have:

```
$ awk '
    $1~/Engineer/ {if ($3~/Engineer/) next; print}
    $3~/Engineer/ {if ($1~/Engineer/) next; print}
' file
Position:"Engineer" Name:"Jes" Position:"Accountant" Name:"Criss"
```

Answer (score 0):

With two `grep`s in a pipe:

```
grep -F 'Position:"Engineer"' file | grep -Ev '(Position:"[^"]*").*\1'
```

or, perhaps more robustly

```
grep -F 'Position:"Engineer"' file | grep -v 'Position:"Engineer".*Position:"Engineer"'
```

In general case, if you want to print the lines with unique `Position` fields,

```
grep -Ev '(Position:"[^"]*").*\1' file
```

should do the job, assuming all the lines have the format specified. This will work also when there are more than two `Position` fields in the line.

Answer (score 0):

Use negative lookahead to exclude a pattern after match.

```
grep 'Position:"Engineer"' | grep -P 'Position:"(?!Engineer)'
```